# SQLite error on Create table

Tags: sql, sqlite

This :

```
create table cartao(
    _id integer primary autoincrement, 
    nome text not null
    );
create table vacina(
    _id integer primary autoincrement, 
    idCartao long not null, 
    nome text not null, 
    descricao text not null
);
create table remedio(
    _id integer primary autoincrement, 
    nome text not null
    );

SELECT * FROM CARTAO;
```

Return the following error :

> Error: near "autoincrement": syntax error

Comment: At the very least, isolate the query that causes the problem.  Put some effort into asking the question.

Comment: 1) Bugged Query ; 2) Clean Error; 3) [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Off Topic] In SQLite, `AUTOINCREMENT` without the `_` is OK

---

[**You forgot `KEY` after `PRIMARY` :**](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

It should be **`_id integer primary key autoincrement`**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/0e5d8/1)

**SQLite (SQL.js) Schema Setup**:

```
create table cartao(_id integer primary key autoincrement, nome text not null);

Insert into cartao(nome) Values('test 1'),('test 2');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM CARTAO
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/0e5d8/1/0)**:

```
| _id |   nome |
|-----|--------|
|   1 | test 1 |
|   2 | test 2 |
```

Answer (score -2):

use **AUTO_INCREMENT** instead of autoincrement in the queries

Comment: E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: br.com.immunize.navigationdrawer, java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.immunize.navigationdrawer/br.com.immunize.navigationdrawer.NAVI.Activities.CartaoActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table cartao(_id integer primary AUTO_INCREMENT, nome text not null); help

Comment: http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html => `AUTOINCREMENT`, no `_` with SQLite...